# Expo GoogleSignIn initAsync method is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, google-signin

Following the expo documentation, I was able to set up google sign in and it worked perfectly. But after I executed

expo build: android

to create an apk file.

The Google sign in no longer worked.

I checked up the expo documentation and I found out for stand-alone apps I had to use the GoogleSignIn.

So I did just that.

This is my code:

```
  async signInWithGoogleAsync(){
    try{
      await GoogleSignIn.askForPlayServicesAsync();
      const {type,user}= await GoogleSignIn.initAsync({
        clientId:'MY_CLIENT_ID_FROM_GoogleService-Info.plist'
      })

      if(type === 'success'){
        this.onSignIn(result);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Authenticated');
        return result.accessToken;
      }else
        alert("Type: "+type);
        return {canceled:true}
      }
    }catch(e){
      alert("catch: "+e)
    }
  }
```

This was supposed to give get google sign in work on my stand-alone APK file. But i got an error in my catch block.

Error:

```
    TypeError: 
    l.initAsync is not a function. 
    (ln 'l.initAsunc({clientId: MY_CLIENT_ID});
     'l.initAsync' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

import * as GoogleSignIn from 'expo-google-sign-in';